# How to remove a string from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, remove-method

I am trying to remove a string from a BST and I cannot figure it out. I know how to remove integers but cannot convert my code to remove Nodes that have strings. Here is the code I currently have

```
    /*
     * Removes the specified string from the BST
     */

    public boolean remove(String s){
        Node ans = remove(root, s);
        if(ans == null){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static Node remove(Node root, String s) {

        if (root == null)
            return null;

        if (s.compareTo(root.data) < 0) {
            root.left = remove(root.left, s);
        } else if (s.compareTo(root.data) > 0) {
            root.right = remove(root.right, s);
        } else {

            if (root.left == null) {
                return root.right;
            } else if (root.right == null)
                return root.left;

            root.data = minimum(root.right);
            root.right = remove(root.right, root.data);
        }

        return root;

    }

    public static String minimum(Node root) {
        String minimum = root.data;
        while (root.left != null) {
            minimum = root.left.data;
            root = root.left;
        }
        return minimum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all "Integer" with "String" .

Answer (score 0):

I know this was 2 years ago but I case someone needs help I did this instead..

```
private String minimum(BSTNode treeRoot) {
    String minimum = treeRoot.value;
    while (treeRoot.left != null) {
        minimum = treeRoot.left.value;
        treeRoot = treeRoot.left;
    }
    return minimum;
}

private BSTNode removeValue(BSTNode treeRoot, String s){
    if(treeRoot == null){
        return treeRoot;
    } else if(s.compareTo(treeRoot.value) < 0){
        treeRoot.left = removeValue(treeRoot.left, s);
    } else if(s.compareTo(treeRoot.value) > 0){
        treeRoot.right = removeValue(treeRoot.right, s);
    } else {
        if(treeRoot.left == null){
            return treeRoot.right;
        } else if(treeRoot.right == null){
            return treeRoot.left;
        }

        treeRoot.value = minimum(treeRoot.right);
        treeRoot.right = removeValue(treeRoot.right, treeRoot.value);
    }

    return treeRoot;
}
```